# how to create access provider function in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

i am trying to build form using JSON. I am using below library to generate form.

https://www.react-hook-form.com/

issue .: I am trying to access hook function on Parent component . But I am not able to access. Any suggestion how to access hooks methods on Parent component . shall I create a new **Provider** or contest and Wrap that **Provider** **Frombuilder** component . Shall it works ?

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-form-context-forked-hlq9hm?file=/src/index.js

```
function App() {
  // const methods = useForm();

  const onChange = () => {
    console.log("000000");
    //methods.setValue("firstName", "asdasd");
  };

  // const { registerState, handleSubmit } = methods;

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };
  return (
    <FormBuilder
      jsonSchema={json}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      onSubmitHandler={onSubmit}
      functionHandler={{
        onChange: onChange
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

I want to access setValue , getValue function on App component . is it possible ?

**can I create one more provider or any ref ?**

need to get hook function linke  setValue, getValue.

I am trying like this . when I am changing select box option . On change handler below function called.

```
 const onChange = () => {
    console.log("000000");
    //methods.setValue("firstName", "asdasd");
  };
```

any idea to create wrapper hook ?

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have passed `methods` from your App to the FormBuilder:

[image: Edit React Hook Form - V7 - Form Context (forked)]

In the App you define methods:

```
const methods = useForm();
```

Pass it to FormBuilder:

```
<FormBuilder
    methods={methods}
```

In the FormBuilder pass it to the provider (as you already did)

```
 <FormProvider {...methods}>
```

The problem was that you didn't pass your methods to the provider.

Comment: is it a correct way ??

Comment: @user5711656 It is a working way ;) I don't think creating another provider would work.

Comment: can I create a another hook and return all methods from that ?

Comment: @user5711656 I don't understand what do u mean by "another hook" but `methods` constant you use to setValue should be passed to the original FormProvider.

Comment: actually my concern was if I want to multiple place in application I always want to send `const methods = useForm();` in all place

Comment: I am thinking bettor ways